# responsive column view in ionic

Tags: angular, css, ionic-framework

I have to show the iterated items in a view,the no of items per row should be responsive as per the display size.and each items should be in the same dimension.
[image: My current view1][image: My current view2]

**home.html**

```
 <ion-row>
   <ion-col *ngFor="let item of allservices; let i = index">
      <div (click)="gotoSpecificService(item)">
        <img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Share/icon/color/Gaming//snorlax1600.png"/>
        <p>{{item.name}}</p>
       </div>
   </ion-col>
 </ion-row>
```

In the following images Servic 7 have different dimension than other images.How to make all images are in same dimension as well as responsive?

Comment: Is number of images is always fix i.e. 6?

Comment: @VicJordan No.The content is dynamic

Comment: Provide fiddle sample code.